# I can't use @yield correctly

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using two @yield on one page for the main content and the second for navbar, but navbar is not showing at all, I'm new to laravel and must have learned some concept the wrong way.
The project follows the following folder structure

```
views /
      component / navbar.blade.php
      layouts / main.blade.php
      reviewer / reviewer.blade.php
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('reviewer', 'ReviewerController');
```

ReviewerController.php

```
public function index(){
        $title = "All Project";
        $projects = session('projects');
        return view('reviewer.index', compact(['projects','title']));
    }
```

main.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace(' _', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('navbar')
        @yield('conteudo')        
    </body>
</html>
```

reviewer.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('conteudo')

<h3> {{$title}} <h3>

<ul>
    @foreach( $projects as $p )
        <li> {{ $p['id'] }} | {{ $p['name'] }} | {{ $p['appraiser']}} | {{ $p['student'] }} </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

@endsection
```

navbar.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('navbar')
    <div id='menu'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edital</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resultados</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bem vindo user</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: That's not how `@yield()` works. In the `.blade` that extends `layouts.main`, you'd need an `@section('sidebar')`. You might as well just do an `@include('sidebar')` in `layouts.main`, with just the HTML.

Comment: So from what I understand, should I change the name of my yield (navbar) to yield (sidebar)?

Comment: Sorry, no, that's not the point; I misread the variable name. My point is, if you use `@yield()`, you need an `@section()` to match, and you don't have one in `reviewer.blade.php`. You can just use `@include('navbar')` directly in `main.blade.php`, and get rid of `@extends()` and `@section` in `navbar.blade.php`

Comment: Works perfectly with include, is still a little weak or because it doesn't consume using "two" yields but you can look in the application.

Comment: Yes, you can use two `@yield()`, that's fine, but in this case it doesn't make much sense, unless every view had a different navbar. The bigger issue here was having two files with `@extends()`; you can only return 1 view, and that should be the one that extends another, so unless you did `view("navbar")`, that wasn't going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this your main.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace(' _', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        @include(' component.navbar')
        @yield('conteudo')        
    </body>
</html>
```

reviewer.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('conteudo')

<h3> {{$title}} <h3>

<ul>
    @foreach( $projects as $p )
        <li> {{ $p['id'] }} | {{ $p['name'] }} | {{ $p['appraiser']}} | {{ $p['student'] }} </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

@endsection
```

navbar.blade.php

```
<div id='menu'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edital</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resultados</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bem vindo user</a></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

ReviewController.php

```
public function index(){
        $title = "All Project";
        $projects = session('projects');
        return view('reviewer.reviewer', compact(['projects','title']));
    }
```